# Do something with .each id of a string broken by ,

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

Hello I have a var called numbers which is a string of number broken by a , 
I need to use each of these to do something with. Can anyone help me fill in the missing part:

```
var numbers = 1313,1314,1252,1244,1223,34,123,1,245;

(FOR Each number of numbers set AS numbersSingle)
     var numbersSingle = 1313;
    $(".notification").remove("#" + messageSingle);
```

I hope this makes sense, if anyone needs anymore information please let me know, thanks all!

Comment: each element has specific id hence no need to use class specifier, Simply remove the item by its id.

Comment: do you want to split the variable on "," and get all the numbers? I din't understand what you want to convey by using the for each loop here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop here. You can amend the string to form a valid selector with each id separated by a string, eg: `#1313,#1314...` etc, and then remove them all in a single operation. Try this

```
var numbers = "1313,1314,1252,1244,1223,34,123,1,245";
$('.notification').remove('#' + numbers.replace(',', ',#'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
var numbers = ("1313,1314,1252,1244,1223,34,123,1,245").split(",");

for (var a = 0; a < numbers.length; a++) {
  $(".notification").remove("#"+numbers[a]);
}
```

Comment: array indexes are zero based, so `a = 0`. Also you don't need to wrap the string in brackets.

Comment: yeah fixed that, thanks. I like to add bracket around string, it add more clarity for me i guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
var numArray = numbers.split(',');

for (var x = 0; x < numArray.length; x ++) {
    console.log(numArray[x]);
}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lm1jhd8/) - open the console to see output.

The bit you're missing is the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function that converts a string to an array based on a separator.

You can use other loops on the array if you prefer - there's some more [detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the var is a string.

```
var numberArray = numbers.split(',') //This will return an array with earch element split by a comma.
```

iterate through the array using

```
numberArray.each(function(e){
  console.log(e); //do what ever you want for each value.
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use split and $.each from jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var numbers = "1313,1314,1252,1244,1223,34,123,1,245";
    var numbersArr = numbers.split(",");
     $.each(numbersArr,function(key, value) {
          console.log(value);
     });
   });
```

where value is each value from your numbers

> ref [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)
>
> ref [$.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/)